# Advanced Macroeconomics David Romer Chapter 10

Tags: macroeconomics

I am currently reading David Romer's Advanced Macroeconomics for self study. Could someone please kindly explain to me how to derive (10.21) from chapter 10 in more detail than the textbook?
[image]